# REPLICATE() return type for VARBINARY input

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, string-manipulation

```
REPLICATE ( string_expression ,integer_expression )
```

As [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replicate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) says, it

> returns the same type as *string_expression*.

I see that return type is always `VARCHAR`.

```
declare @vb varbinary(10) = 0x01
declare @res sql_variant = REPLICATE(@vb, 2)

SELECT sql_variant_property(@res, 'BaseType')
```

> varchar

Is the documentation wrong?

I raised this as a documentation [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/3826).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be mainly a documentation issue. I had originally thought that this was a bug within the `REPLICATE` function, but I've done a bit of testing across most other string functions and have found that this behavior is common among *most* of them.  To summarize, this behavior is:

1. If there is one "string" parameter and `VARBINARY` is passed in, it is assumed to be `VARCHAR` in the code page associated with the database's default collation.
2. If there are multiple "string" parameters:

   1. If all string params are passed in as `VARBINARY`, they are assumed to be `VARCHAR`
   2. If one or more params are passed in as `VARCHAR` and none as `NVARCHAR`, the `VARBINARY` is assumed to be `VARCHAR`
   3. If any string params are passed in as `NVARCHAR`, the `VARBINARY` is assumed to be `NVARCHAR`

As far as I can tell, the only string function that will return `VARBINARY` given `VARBINARY` input is `SUBSTRING`.

So the problem is really that the documentation isn't specific enough. The statement:

> *string_expression* can be either character or binary data.

is not incorrect. It just doesn't state that binary data will be implicitly converted to `VARCHAR`. If this were to be stated, then getting `VARCHAR` output for `VARBINARY` input makes sense, and thus the statement:

> Returns the same type as *string_expression*.

is also not incorrect.

This behavior, of course, would ideally be noted across all of the functions that it pertains to, and not just this one.

I have already added this info to the [documentation issue on GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/3826#issuecomment-567325217) that was opened by the O.P..

Comment: The documentation for `+` 'string' concatenation is no better. Consider `@vb + @vb` returns `varbinary`.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that `REPLICATE` is expecting a string not a binary type, and an implicit conversion is taking place from `VARBINARY` to `VARCHAR`. If you update your example like so you get the expected type:

```
declare @vb nvarchar(10) = '#'
declare @res sql_variant = REPLICATE(@vb, 2)
SELECT sql_variant_property(@res, 'BaseType')
```

Even though it accepts a binary input, the spec does specifically state that parameter is a "string expression" which is why I suspect type coercion is happening *before* the function is actually run. By "expected type" I am referring to it not being fixed as `VARCHAR` irrespective of input type which might be implied when looking in your result on its own. So I think the documentation is correct, but perhaps not perfectly clear: the function returns the same `[N][VAR]CHAR(<len>)` type that is receives, and in your test it is receiving a `VARCHAR()` due to implicit conversion from `VARBINARY` to `VARCHAR`.

Answer (score 1):

By performing a little sleight-of-hand with SQL I can get SSMS to show an execution plan. This:

```
select REPLICATE(@vb, 2) where 1 = 1;
```

Has a single CONSTANT SCAN showing the implicit conversion, as David surmised:

[image]

Comment: Yep, it makes this conversion visible. Good way to check what's going on BTW, thank you.